# A query body must end with a select clause

Tags: c#, linq

I’m trying to delete the last row of a datagridview programmatically, but I’m unable.  Here’s what I’ve tried so far

```
DataGridViewRow LastRow = (from @this in DataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                           where !@this.IsNewRow).LastOrDefault;
if (LastRow != null) {
   DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(LastRow);
}
```

this error is raised

> A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Comment: from [...] in [...] where [...] SELECT [...]

Comment: There is another error there `LastOrDefault` is a function, should be changed to `LastOrDefault()` BTW, I wonder if it is already answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As error says you need to add a `select` clause to your query:

   ```
   from @this in DataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
   where !@this.IsNewRow
   select @this
   ```
2. And you forgot the brackets around `LastOrDefault`:

   ```
   DataGridViewRow LastRow = (from @this in DataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                              where !@this.IsNewRow
                              select @this).LastOrDefault();
   ```

---

In addition in my opinion using method syntax for this case is nicer. Both shorter and allows you to place the predicate in the `LastOrDefault`:

```
var result = DataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().LastOrDefault(r => !r.IsNewRow);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. works like a charm

Comment: @SharmaHussein - you are welcome :) I recommend that you take a little step back and read a bit about linq and query syntax :)